# Approximate the mean area of 2D Voronoi cell

Tags: approximation, geometry, voronoi

Consider a random uniform distribution of $N$ points in $2D$ space bounded by $[0, 1]$ in both dimensions. Example:

[image]

If I want to estimate the mean area of their Voronoi cells, I have to obtain the Voronoi diagram for this distribution, calculate the areas associated to each point, and finally obtain their mean. This is a time-consuming process.

Given that this is a random uniform distribution of points, I thought I could just approximate this area with:

$$\hat{A}\approx\frac{1}{N}$$

i.e., the total area of the $2D$ space ($1*1=1$) divided by the number of points ($N$). I wrote some code to test this approximation, the results are as shown:

[image]

where the $y$ axis is the relative difference $100 * (\hat{A_{V}}-\hat{A})/\hat{A_{V}}$ ($\hat{A_{V}}$ is the real area), and $N$ is the number of points. This shows that $\hat{A}$ underestimates the real value $\hat{A_{V}}$ by ~30% for small $N$, and tends to zero as it grows.

Is there a better approximation (particularly for mall $N$ values)?

---

**Add**

After whuber's comment I re-checked my code. I was using a somewhat convoluted method involving nearest neighbors to assign areas to unbounded points (close to the edges of the frame). I changed it to instead assign to these points the $1/N$ average area, and the results improved considerably (as expected). Here are the results:

[image]

Now it shows that the $1/N$ approximated area underestimates the "true" mean area (which actually depends on the technique used to handle unbounded points) for small $N$ but quickly goes to zero as $N$ grows.

Comment: There is a one-to-one correspondence between the Voronoi cells and the points, whence there are always $N$ cells with total area $1:$ their mean is $1/N.$  If your code is producing anything else, it must be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks whuber. I re-checked my code and it appears the reason for the difference was my method to handle unbounded points. I simplified it and now it shows much better results.

Comment: The correct method is to clip the Voronoi regions to the rectangle before computing areas.

Comment: I do that (now) but `scipy`'s implementation will return "bad" indexes (-1) when the point's area is unbounded. These indexes are filled with "incorrect" points (located inside the frame) For these cases I can not clip the regions, hence I assign $A=1/N$.

Comment: This is what I mean about -1 indexes in `scipy`'s Voronoi implementation correctly explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39476507/1391441